# why position of BottomNavigationView depends on ScrollView scrollbars?

Tags: android, android-scrollview, bottomnavigationview, scrollbars

Hi I'm little bit confused about `BottomNavigationView` position behavior.

**Why is enabling/disabling of scrollbars affecting resizing of layout and position of `BottomNavigationView`?**

I created simple example project to show my problem...

With this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="sandbox.jarda.cz.bottomnavigationtest.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="test" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Will the `BottomNavigationView` stay under the Keyboard (when is opened)...

[image: <code>BottomNavigationView</code> is under the keyboard]

**BUT :)**

When I delete line/enable scroll bars

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

The main layout is "resized" and the `BottomNavigationView` is on the top of the keyboard...

[image: <code>BottomNavigationView</code> is on the top of the keyboard]

**WHY?**

Thx for answer:)

Answer (score 3):

This is not because of scrolling, this is because of **keyboard behaviour** of your application.

you need to specify `windowSoftInputMode` in your `activity` tag of your `manifest`
for more about `windowSoftInputMode` check this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

```
<application ... >
<activity
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" ... >
    ...
</activity>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

it is not because of scrollbars just you need to just  specify windowSoftInputMode use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` in your activity in manifest tag like this

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Yep, It is working => BottomNavigationView is under the keyboard...but my question was targeting on WHY scrollbars are affecting that? :)

Comment: @Jarda **"adjustResize"** is important if your UI includes controls that the user might need to access immediately after or while performing text input. **For example**, if you use a relative layout to place a button bar at the bottom of the screen, using "adjustResize" resizes the layout so the button bar appears above the input method.

Comment: i think is not because of scrollbars@Jarda

Comment: Yeah thx...its probably not because of scrollbars but I was surprised that change of the scrollbars element changed the resizing behavior...

Answer (score 1):

The reason is ScrollView. When you open keyboard, it resizes itself with available space excluding keyboard + height of bottom navigation view.

When Keyboard not showing it uses available height, excluding height of navigation view.

---

For more clarity, implement keyboard listener and there calculate height of scroll view. You can modify below code for that

Calling code. Can be into `onCreate`

`container.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(mOnGlobalLayoutListener); // Here container is topmost LinearLayout in your layout`

And `mOnGlobalLayoutListener` would be

```
private ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener mOnGlobalLayoutListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Rect r = new Rect();
        mActivityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
        int screenHeight = mActivityRootView.getRootView().getHeight();
        int keyboardheight = screenHeight - r.bottom;
        /**
         *
         * We are taking 15% of the screen height as it should be sufficient space for the keyboard to determine if keyboard is open.
         */
        if (keyboardheight > screenHeight * 0.15) {
            // Keyboard showing
            // PRINT HEIGHT OF SCROLLVIEW while keyboard is showing
        } else {
            // Keyboard hidden
            // PRINT HEIGHT OF SCROLLVIEW while keyboard not showing 
        }
    }
};
```